# List S3 Bucket keys in a listview winform c#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

So I'm trying to list the files in my S3 bucket to my winform in visual studio c#

```
static async Task ListingObjectAsync()
{
    try
    {
        ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
        {
            BucketName = bucketName
        };
        ListObjectsV2Response response;
        do
        {
            response = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);

            foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
            {
                string file = entry.Key;
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(file);
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        } while (response.IsTruncated);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
   
}
```

But it says that "an object reference is required for a non static field"

Any tips on how to list files from S3 bucket to listview, datagrid or other forms?

Thank you!
P.S. I'm new to stack overflow so I'm sorry if my question format is wrong

Comment: *it says that ...* where does it say that?

Comment: listView1 is considered an error and when I hover my mouse on it it shows " CS0120: An object is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'S3.listView1' "

Comment: @MongZhu I'm pretty sure that's from the AWS SDK. Edit: [Yep, it is](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TListObjectsV2Response.html)

Comment: where exactly is this method `static async Task ListingObjectAsync()` situated? In your `Form` class? normally you cannot access instance variables in a static method. Why did you make the method static in the first place?

Comment: @John thank you. I was on the wrong track. I guess the error is due to that static nature of the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `static` from your method declaration:

```
async Task ListingObjectAsync(){...}
```

you cannot access instance variables from a static method

Comment: Thank you! It resolved the error! Though I still can't list my S3 Bucket in listview. But still thank you.

Comment: @Jacent you're welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow. Best way of saying thank you here is to mark the answer that helped you as accepted. Click the check icon. " I still can't list my S3 Bucket in listview." what is the problem now?